# UMP Test for exponential random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_i\sim \text{Exp}(\theta)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ i.i.d with density
\begin{equation*}
    f(x,\theta) =
    \begin{cases}
        \theta \exp(-x\theta ),& x\geq 0\\
        0,& x< 0.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
I want to test the hypothesis
\begin{equation*}
    H_0: \theta = \theta_0 \quad \text{vs} \quad H_1: \theta = \theta_1 \quad \text{with}\quad \theta_1 > \theta_0
\end{equation*}
The Neyman-Pearson lemma provides a UMP test at level $\alpha$ of the form
\begin{equation}
      \varphi^*(X) = 
        \begin{cases}
          1, & \hspace{0.25cm} f_1(X) > k f_0(X),\\
          0, & \hspace{0.25cm} f_1(X) < k f_0(X).
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}

For some critical value $k$. The densities are absolutely continious, therefore we can look at the likelihood ratio. Since they are i.i.d this is just the product of the respective densities and we get
\begin{equation*}
\frac{f(X,\theta_1)}{f(X,\theta_0)}=\frac{\theta_1^{n}\exp(-\theta_1\sum_{i=1}^n x_i )}{\theta_0\exp(-\theta_0\sum_{i=1}^n x_i )} = \frac{\theta_1^n}{\theta_0^n}\exp\left(-(\theta_1-\theta_0)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)>k.
\end{equation*}
My problem arises, when I rearrange this term to get an equivalent condition.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\theta_1^n}{\theta_0^n}\exp\left(-(\theta_1-\theta_0)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)&>k \\
n\log(\theta_1/\theta_0)-(\theta_1-\theta_0)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i&>k'\\
-(\theta_1-\theta_0)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i&>k'-n\log(\theta_1/\theta_0)\\
-\frac{(\theta_1-\theta_0)}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i&>k'/n-\log(\theta_1/\theta_0)\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i&<\frac{k'/n-\log(\theta_1/\theta_0)}{(\theta_1-\theta_0)}=:k''.\\
\end{align*}
The inequality switches in the last step since we assume $\theta_1>\theta_0$. However this seems odd. Using some probability theory we calculate $k''$ for $\alpha=0.05$. Since the sum of i.i.d exponential r.v. is $Gamma(n,\theta)$ and $Gamma(n,1/2) = \chi^2(2n)$ this results in the condition
\begin{equation*}\alpha  = \mathcal{P}_{\theta_0}(\overline{X}_n <k'') = \mathcal{P}_{\theta_0}(2\theta_0n\overline{X}_n <2\theta_0nk'').
\end{equation*}
Thus we get $2\theta_0nk''= \chi^2_{1-\alpha}(2n)$, where the subscript denotes the $1-\alpha$ quantile. Therefore, $$ k''=\frac{\chi^2_{1-\alpha}(2n)}{2\theta_0n}.$$

The reason why the condition $\overline{X}_n <k''$ seems odd is the following simulation for a sample of 15 exponential r.v. with parameter $\theta = 1$, where i test $\theta_0 = 1$  vs $\theta_1 = 2$. The likehood ratio process goes very nicely to $0$, as one would expect with how i chose the values. However the condition for the sample mean would reject the null in favor of the paramter $\theta_1$, since the sample mean is lower than the critical value $k''$ (in the image discription it says k'). This cannot be right, therefore I assume an error when calculating $k''.$

[image: Likelihood-Ratio-Process]

and [image: Sum as statistic for rejection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crucial error have been made during the calculation:

- The sum of exponential r.v. with rate parameter $\theta$ is $Gamma(n,\theta)$, therefore $1/n * Gamma(n,\theta) \sim Gamma(n,n\theta)$ thus I needed not look at the mean as the statistic, the sum would have been sufficient.
- For calculating $k''$: the probabilty $\mathcal{P}(X<k'')=\alpha$ for a r.v. $X$ means $k''$ is precisely the $\alpha$ quantile, not the $1-\alpha$ quantile of the distribution of $X$. Therefore, $$k''= \frac{\chi^2_\alpha(2n)}{2\theta_0 n}$$ when the mean is the equivalent statistic. If the sum is used as an equivalent statistic $$k''= \frac{\chi^2_\alpha(2n)}{2\theta_0}.$$